# Does an SQL Database return a type, or does the Database Abstraction Layer perform implicit casting? (Propel and php)

Tags: php, mysql, propel, dbal

A simple Propel query to fetch a result `100` from a column with type `VARCHAR` returns a string.  This is expected behaviour.  I am working with a legacy system and know I need to cast these values to a php `integer` type in order to sort them programatically or perform arithmetic etc.

Does the Database explicitly return a `VARCHAR` and if so how does this work for a weakly typed language?

Alternatively, does the DBAL look at the column type and perform an implicit cast on that basis?

To put it another way: **Is the column type in SQL just a 'tag' or 'label' which is interpreted by the DBAL which then casts appropriately based on language?**

To keep the question specific, I'd like an answer with regards to: `Propel`, `php` and `MySQL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you properly, you are asking if the database uses a binary format to store the data.  Yes it does. The layer(s) between the database and the application is what determines what format is returned to the application.

It is actually just the opposite of your question - the DBAL receives typed information, which is then translated to whatever the application can handle.

Answer (score 0):

Varchar is basically a character type that stringify the numbers as characters. SQL only allows you to only customize the column as a whole. Extracting a single value and changing its data type is something of a practice I never came across. Although it would be really powerful. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Oh yes.  I know the entire column has a type in SQL.  I am more wondering if that type in SQL is more just a 'tag' or 'label' which is interpreted by the DBAL which then casts appropriately based on language.

Comment: The data types are hard coded within the server and not just a mere name of a label. You might want to look into MongoDB in that case. It might work out for you.